# Excel Nested IF statements with ISBLANK, AND, and NOT ISBLANK

Tags: excel, if-statement

Here's the formula I've entered:

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F2),(NOT(ISBLANK(G2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",G2," pcs/box")),
IF(AND(ISBLANK(G2),(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",F2," sf/box")),
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F2), (NOT(ISBLANK(G2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",F2," sf/box - ",G2," pcs/box")),"")
```

This is to format a spreadsheet to concatenate fields and text depending on whether fields do or do not have data.  I've included `""` at the end for the final else. Excel is telling me that I've entered too many arguments for this function.  One that is simpler (where I only have one if, then an else) is working.  But there are times when I need to check for additional empty fields.  (Or cells)  So, the first IF would give the tile name`(B2) - #(G2) pcs/box`.  The second IF would give the tile name`(B2) - #(F2) sf/box`.  The third IF would give the tile name`(B2) - #(F@) sf/box - #G2) pcs/box`.  The final `""` would give a blank. I hope you can help.  I've looked everywhere.  I'm stumped.  I've looked at the `()` to make sure they're matched.

Comment: What Excel version do you have?

Comment: Microsoft Home & Office 2016

Comment: You can try to simplify you formula using the [IFS](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/ifs.html#:~:text=Use%20the%20IFS%20function%20in,can%20nest%20the%20IF%20function.) function

Answer (score 1):

Your brackets are a little off. Try this one.

```
=IF(AND(ISBLANK(F2),(NOT(ISBLANK(G2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",G2," pcs/box"),IF(AND(ISBLANK(G2),(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",F2," sf/box"),IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)),(NOT(ISBLANK(G2)))),CONCATENATE(B2," - ",F2," sf/box - ",G2," pcs/box"),"")))
```

Comment: I adjusted the brackets per above, but it didn't make a difference.  I really appreciate all of the replies!  All of you are SO thoughtful!  You even answered right away!

Comment: Try Scott Craner's solution. He is much, much smarter than I am.

Answer (score 1):

A little simpler:

```
=IF(OR(F2<>"",G2<>""),B2&IF(F2<>""," - "&F2&" sf/box","")&IF(G2<>""," - "&G2&" pcs/box",""),"")
```